# Where is GraphDB jar file?

Tags: graphdb

I am trying to use a GraphDB repository from a Maven project using Eclipse Neon with builtin Maven. Where can I find the GraphDB runtime jar file to place in local Maven repository? Why GraphDB is not available from Maven Central?

*update* I have created a GraphDB repository and it works fine. Now I would like to setup a Maven project in Eclipse Neon to interact with the repository programmatically. GraphDB is not available from Maven central. Developer Hub instructs users to run "MVN Install" to install GraphDB runtime jar into local Maven repository. Since I am using Eclipse Neon with integrated Maven, there is no (I cannot find) MVN executable to run "MVN Install". So my question is what file(s) should I transfer manually to my local Maven repository?

Comment: Please, add more details to your question. Show your code, maybe your `pom.xml`, so people can try to find an error. Also, consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have created a GraphDB repository and it works fine. Now I would like to setup a Maven project in Eclipse Neon to interact with the repository programmatically. GraphDB is not available from Maven central. Developer Hub instructs users to run "MVN Install" to install GraphDB runtime jar into local Maven repository. Since I am using Eclipse Neon with integrated Maven, there is no (I cannot find) MVN executable to run "MVN Install". So my question is what file(s) should I transfer manually to my local Maven repository? This may be a stupid question for a pro. Unfortunately, I am not a pro.

Comment: @adel-karsh thanks for the explanation. As a tip: next time please [edit] your question instead of adding this info as a comment (I've done it for you this time around). As for why GraphDB is not in Maven Central: Maven Central is only intended for open-source projects. GraphDB is free, but not open-source.

Answer (score 0):

The jar files that you need are the ones that are located in the installed folder of GrpahDB "app/lib". You just add them to the Build Path in eclipse and copy the Java class EmbebbedGraphDB that is in the examples folder.